# Printing Arabic using DOS command

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to print Arabic using dos print command in vb script? Eg:

```
//Printer.Print esc & "%0" & esc & "V000" //
```

By changing some arguments in this code can we print Arabic directly ? –

Comment: What is the "DOS print command" you speak of?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that VB Script does not work in DOS - do you happen to mean the commandline window in modern Windows versions?

Comment: I am fetching Arabic description from SQL db and printing using vb code. And above posted code fragment is being currently used which gives garbage values. the printer we use is a bar-code printer not normal one.